# Adb logcat extended data and how to read it

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, adb, logcat

When I run the `adb logcat` command on the `shell` it seems different from what `Android Studio` gives me when I read the logcat there.

For example, the date is in compact format.

The pid (what I believe is the pid, the third field) on the shell is separated by a space `(5264 4817)`.

Instead when I look at the logcat from android studio it is separated by a line `(5264-4817)`.

Is there a way to get the extended format?

The package of the app in use is missing, which instead appears on android studio.

P.S.

Can you tell me exactly how to read it?

For example, from what I understand they are divided like this:

```
date, time, pid, priority, other??
```